# How to check $_POST form data values for multiple conditions in Php using nested if statements?

Tags: php, html, css, validation, multiple-conditions

I am building an html program that takes in fields of "Last Name, First Name, User ID, and an array of Values."( Values will be used to calculate and display the mean, min, and max of it's given dataset). Now I need to only allow valid input to display these things in a table in a text file. I was using html's required pattern tags, but that will not work for this project. I need to check the $_POST variables in php statements before I fwrite() them to my text output. Is there any way anyone can give me some direction on how to set up these validation checkers in php for my given conditions?

The Conditions are as follows:

•   No field is allowed to be blank.
•   Maximum length of first and last name is 20 characters.
•   The first and last names should be only made up of alphabetical characters.  (no numbers or symbols).  Only a-z, and A-Z.  Any ordering of lower/uppercase letters is acceptable.
•   User ID must be 3 lowercase letters followed by 3 numbers.  Example: abc123
•   Values has a max length of 50 characters.  It is a comma separated list of values, with each value in the range 0.0 to 100.0.
•   Every value must have 1 digit after the decimal point.
•   Every value must have 1,2, or 3 digits before the decimal point (i.e. .7 is not a valid value in our system, but 0.7 is valid).

My Html code for my inputs is:

```
/head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" action="UpdateInfo.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold"> User Info</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>First Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="fname" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" title="Max 20 Characters, only A-Z or a-z"  maxlength = 20 /> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Last Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="lname" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" title="Max 20 Characters, only A-Z or a-z"  maxlength = 20  /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>ID Number:</td><td><input type="text" name="id" required pattern=[a-z]{3}[1-9]{3} title="Must be abc123 format!" maxlength="6" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>List of values: </td><td><input type="text" name="listOfValues"  maxlength="50" />
</tr>
```

My php code is this so far:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") //post request w/o post data
{
$fname = $_POST['fname']; //sets new variables = to our post data inputs
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$userID=$_POST['id'];
$valuesList=explode(',', $_POST['listOfValues']);

if(empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($userID) || empty($valuesList) ) //condition to check if any of these variables are empty
{
echo '<p style="color:red"> Please, Fill the text box before submitting data!</p>';
}
else{
$path="UserInfo.txt";
$fo= fopen($path,'a') or die('Cannot open file'); //fo = the open version of the UserInfo.txt file
$maxOfList = max($valuesList);
$minOfList = min($valuesList);

fwrite($fo, "| Last Name: ".$lname. "| "); //so if these variables are filled correctly then the machine will print them into the UserInfo.txt file
fwrite($fo, "| First Name: ".$fname. "| ");
fwrite($fo, "| UserID: ".$userID. "| ");
fwrite($fo, "| Minimum: " . $minOfList. "| ");
fwrite($fo, "| Maximum: " . $maxOfList. "| ". "\n");
//fwrite($fo, "Values: ".$valuesList. " " ."\n");
fclose($fo);

$fo = fopen($path, 'r') or die('Cannot open file');
while(!feof($fo))
{
echo fgets($fo)."<br>";
}

fclose($fo);
}

}
?>
```

I hope this all makes sense; I am just trying to meet the conditions I set in my html code above, but make my php code check for the validity instead. I don't know the syntax or the order I need to go in to check these conditions. The person who assigned this will not allow me to just use html patterns to stop invalid data. If anyone can help or at least point me in the right direction you will be appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: validation absolutely belongs in the server side, as well as the user side.  Since you know what variables you are expecting, make an array of expected variables.  This array could use the var name as the key, and the value could be a rule or array of rules to validate against.  Iterate through this array, and compare/validate against the matching `%_POST` key.  If any fail to validate, you can build an array of failure messages.  See if that gets you running in the right direction.